# Dynamically assign the final NUM_PAGES of viewpager

Tags: android

I got the screenslider to work from the android [Screenslider](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html),
put a webview in and got it to load the urls i assign to it.
It works fine but now i'd like to control the `private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;`
and dynamically change it from a sqlite database  numrowcount when i move to this activity.
I tried wrappers and then some but it will crash everytime.
My knowledge of java is somewhat limited elas.

Now i know this works in the oncreate

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("urlData", urlData);
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragobj = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

So i assign the url thats being used to get content within the fragment.
Now how do i control the private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5,
and reassign it to whatever number i want or get from the database?
I just cant get why this is such a difficult thing to create
or find on the web.
Seems to me it should be a non final static number.
I know i am totaly not getting it, but someone does ;)
Anybody any idea?

this is the code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


...
    public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        /**
         * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
         */
        private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

    private ViewPager mPager;


    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mm i turn out to be easy just make it non final and slip in a variable (int count) with the constructor.

public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
    public int NUM_COUNT;

     @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_COUNT;
    }
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int count) {
        super(fm);
        this.NUM_COUNT = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

}
```